# How to share HashMap between two application

Tags: java, spring

I have a `HashMap<String,Wallet>`, `Wallet` is a class of bitcoinj. I have tried to save wallet object in redis database using redisson `RMap`, i got stackOverflow Error . So is there any way to share `HashMap` between two application running on different server.

Here is the exception:

> org.redisson.client.RedisException: Unexpected exception
>   while processing command  at
>   org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.convertException(CommandAsyncService.java:321)
>     at
>   org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.get(CommandAsyncService.java:164)
>     at org.redisson.RedissonObject.get(RedissonObject.java:70)  at
>   org.redisson.RedissonMap.put(RedissonMap.java:197)    at
>   com.examples.redis.RedissonedBitcoin.main(RedissonedBitcoin.java:27)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite
>   recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
>   org.bitcoinj.params.TestNet3Params["genesisBlock"]->org.bitcoinj.core.Block["params"]->org.bitcoinj.params.TestNet3Params["genesisBlock"]-

Comment: To interact with server in java application you can use sockets. Read tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best recommendation you can get so far (since root description is very vague) is to develop a simple service which will provide get functionality for the clients. Of course you should also think about security to avoid man in the middle attacks, etc.

If you absolutely do not want to go this way, you can use [Chronicle-Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) which can persist your data on the HDD. Also if you don't have environment restrictions, you can prepare special server with any in-memory database [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/), [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/), Reddis you have already chosen.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Redis to share this data. Redis is used a lot for session storage.

The problem you're facing in jackson is a circular reference.

[Here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences) is an article about how to solve circular references in Jackson.

I would also think about not storing a Map in Redis but rather just store Wallet objects under redis keys so you can fetch a single wallet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with [Apache Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) and the [KeptCollections](https://github.com/anthonyu/KeptCollections) project on Github.  It addresses not only the communication protocols, but also the problems you might otherwise face with concurrent access to your resources.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{  
  final CountDownLatch connectedSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
  ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper("localhost:2181", 20000, new Watcher() {   
          public void process(WatchedEvent we) {
             if (we.getState() == KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
                connectedSignal.countDown();
             }
          }
       });
  Map<String, String> map = new KeptMap(zk, "/mymap", Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
  map.put("key", "value");
  System.out.println(map.get("key"));
 }`

Comment: I have tried keptCollections .. but i am facing issue in it .You can find the code above and pls beautify the code before looking at it . i am getting `null` at `map.get("key")`

Comment: @AjitSoman ZooKeeper has both client and server components.  Do you have a server listening on port 2181 for your request?  You'll find working test cases for KeptMap here: https://github.com/anthonyu/KeptCollections/tree/master/src/test/java/net/killa/kept

Comment: I have installed Zookeeper with this cmd:`sudo apt-get install zookeeperd` and i when i hit this cmd:`sudo service zookeeper status`  it give this result:`zookeeper start/running, process 1011`

Comment: I urge you to start with the working test case I referenced earlier.  If it works, study and adapt it.  If not, create a new question (not a comment) showing what you tried and the specific error message you encounter.  That way, people are better equipped to help you, and others can learn from your efforts.